# Get the correct meta_value with get_post_meta

Tags: posts, array, post-meta

I tried using the function get_post_meta() to get the meta values of my posts. However to my surprise it returns an Array that contains again arrays! So I looked inside the second level array, and was able to get a list of meta values with this code:

```
$postmeta = get_post_meta($resultid, '', true);

foreach ($postmeta as $meta_key => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $kk => $meta_value) {
        echo "$meta_key => $meta_value.\n";
    }
}
```

However, even though I put `$single = true` reading the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ 
It still gives me 2 values for the same meta key.

E.g. I get this list printed:

```
select_inco => fob.
select_inco => fob.
price_input_currency => usd.
price_input_currency => usd.
price_input => 58.
price_input_to => .
price_per => .
price_comments =>
```

**My Question:**

How do I know what the difference is between these double values like `select_inco` and `price_input_currency` and which one is the correct one?

This is how I add and also edit meta_values from a form:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'select_inco', $_POST['select_inco']);
```

Comment: `get_post_meta` is not your problem... check in your code where you are using`add_post_meta` that you also set `$unique` to `true`, or this is what is gonna happen.

Comment: Thanks @majick! I use this code to save my data from a form. The form can be used to either save or edit the metadata of a post, but in both cases I use this query for all fields of the metadata I want to save. → e.g.: update_post_meta($post_id, 'select_inco', $_POST['select_inco']);

Comment: I don't see how this can be it, because `update_post_meta` only works if the meta value *already exists*. If you have multiple values for the same key, I still think it has to be due to `add_post_meta`... in contrast, `add_post_meta` will fail if you set you unique to true and a value already exists. this is why generally best practice is to use something like `if (!add_post_meta($post_id,'select_inco',$_POST['select_inco'],true)) {update_post_meta($post_id,'select_inco',$_POST['select_inco'];}`

Comment: Aww, thanks majick, but as it says in the documentation for [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta): "This may be used in place of add_post_meta() function. The first thing this function will do is make sure that $meta_key already exists on $post_id. If it does not, add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) is called instead and its result is returned."

Comment: wow, sorry, my bad, they must have changed that behaviour. I am not sure it is actually a better idea than having it only update if the value already exists, but guess that's just how it is now. :-/

Comment: That's ok, I still love you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) is simply just a wrapper for [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/). If we look at the source or `get_metadata()`, we will find that, if `$key` is left empty, `$single` is ignored because of the following lines of code which comes before `$single` is applied

```
if ( ! $meta_key ) {
    return $meta_cache;
}
```

So, in your usecase, `$single` never gets to do it's job.

The double key=>value pairs simply means that you have an array of values for that specific key, and the two values in the array are the same value. This is caused by a flaw somewhere in your code which is responsible for saving data to your custom field. You should go and search for that particular piece of code and sort that particular issue.

I cannot tell you which is the correct value and which not, that is something that you also cannot answer. As I said, you will need to sort your code responsible for saving your custom field data.

In the meantime, you can break out of your foreach loop to only get the first value from a custom field, but I do not recommend this as a solution, the solution will involve to sort how you save your custom field data

```
$postmeta = get_post_meta($resultid, '', true);

foreach ($postmeta as $meta_key => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $kk => $meta_value) {
        echo "$meta_key => $meta_value.\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @pieter-goosen , Thanks! 
I use this code to save my data from a form. The form can be used to either save or edit the metadata of a post, but in both cases I use this query for all fields of the metadata I want to save. → e.g.:
update_post_meta($post_id, 'select_inco', $_POST['select_inco']);

Comment: Please file an edit to your question with your code, your code is unreadable in comments

Comment: Dear Pieter! I just found out that update_post_meta has a optional field: "$prev_value" if not used it updates all of the meta_values with what I put in the POST data... This means it wouldn't matter if I get the first or second value inside my double-nested-for each right?